# Game launcher / updater download delta diff

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a launcher for my game (using Unity3d).

I want it to have the following features :

- Compare game version to latest version and update if necessary
- Check files integrity and update if differences are found
- Download/patch needed files

So comparing the game version is easy : I just parse a version.txt file and compare it's value to the latest server version.

Checking file integrity sounds easy too : Make a list of all files in the game folder, order the list, get a checksum and check if it corresponds.

Now here's the difficult part : Downloading the required files.

My first idea was : If a file checksum is different, download that file.
But unity assets are compressed into large files, so even a simple change will lead to the download of a 2gb file...

So I'm now looking for a way do download only the different parts.
I heard about VCDIFF / xdelta, apparently they can be useful to get a "delta patch" of different binaries. Cool.
But how can I compare two folders if one of them is distant, without downloading it all before ?

Could torrent be an answer ?
How are game devs doing this ?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow.  This is not the appropriate place for a question like this.

Comment: @DavidL I know, i'll try gamedev too, but usually SO/unity3d has far better answers.

Comment: Understandable, but it's just simply not the right place.  gamedev would probably be more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the purpose of [Unity's Asset Bundle Technology](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html).  They're fairly straight-forward and will help with your situation. That link to Unity's docs will get you started. I'd also highly recommend checking out their [Best Practices Documentation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/guide-assetbundles-and-resources); there are caveats you should be aware of before attempting to utilize them.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this and if i'm right it can be useful to solve the large file problem, but they say they don't do "differential patching". Is it ok to have ALL of my assets, scripts, models, audio, everything in my game, placed in some assetbundles ?

Comment: Maybe rsync ! Why didn't I think of that !?

Comment: @FLX It wont handle the "differential patching" for you so you're still responsible for writing your own code that manages when to download a new asset bundle.  However, it will hash the contents so if the assets in the bundle change, the hash of the bundle will change and you'll know it's different.  Also, scripts wont go into bundles (they're compiled into your executable) but you can shove assets, models, and audio all in there.

Comment: Alright then i'll give that a try. Should be enough to start ! Thanks a lot.